# TypeError when importing py4j module in a web2py controller

Tags: python, import, module, web2py, py4j

I'm currently having a problem when trying to use py4j on web2py. This is how I'm trying to import it on my web2py controller file:

```
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
```

When loading the page, this is the error I get:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'> Item in ``from list'' not a string
```

However, when running Python on the terminal, the problem does not occur. Running the import line above works perfectly, and communication with my Java application occurs perfectly.

Any ideas?

Additional information:

- Running on Mac OS X 10.6.8
- Python version 2.7.2
- web2py version 2.3.2
- Both web2py and my terminal window are using the same Python version.
- sys.path is equal for both.
- Using the line `import py4j` instead of `from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway` doesn't give me any errors, but I'm not able to use py4j this way (at least I don't know how to)

Let me know if any additional information is needed. Thank you all so much!

Comment: I believe this is not related to py4j, but to web2py so you may want to edit your title to receive further help. Also, you can do import py4j and then gateway = py4j.java_gateway.JavaGateway()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, even though I haven't quite understood the details of why, so any further explanations on that would be greatly appreciated.

The problem was in the URL I was using to access the page. I was using `http://localhost:8000/MyApplicationName/controller`. When I switched to `http://localhost:8000/myapplicationname/controller` (the application name is completely lowercase) things worked fine.

Again, explanations on importing modules relates to the url on web2py are greatly appreciated.